# How to use # in url as a redirect rule in htaccess for apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, .htaccess, rewrite, 301-redirect

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to have the following work:

- I am trying to redirect a url in htaccess
- I am trying to redirect from `example.com/test.html` to `example.com/index#test`

I have the following setup

`RewriteRule ^test.html http://www.example.com/index#test [R=301,L,B]`

However, it is not working because the browser redirects to `http://www.example.com/index%23test` and returns a page not found.

I have tried many different flags without success.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not possible. A hash (#) is never sent to the server: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5

Comment: It is possible. It works the other way around here. The server sends the URL with fragment identifier in the `Location` HTTP header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects answer has a more complete description on what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a friend help me out with this.

`RewriteRule ^test.html http://www.example.com/index#test [R=301,NE,L]`